# Collect a list of unique "Origin" headers from a repeated URL request

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I want to create a list of the *different* response headers I get when querying an URL, I succeeded in doing this this way:

```
import requests
l= []
for _ in(5):
    a = requests.get("https://google.com", allow_redirects=True).headers['Origin']

    if a not in l:
        l.append(a)
```

This is readable but I feel like this is very basic, how would an advanced Pythonista handle this?

Comment: You cannot substantially edit the question after receiving an answer post, as doing so invalidates the answer.  See the [help] for what you can, should, and cannot do after receiving an answer.  I have rolled back your most recent edit accordingly.

Comment: I am not convinced that this code is on-topic. It seems like a snippet that would never be run in isolation. CodeReview does not support the reviewing of snippets. Is this all of the code in your program, or is there more? Why are you gathering origins? Will it actually be from Google, or is that just an example? (Hypotheticals are also off-topic.)

Comment: @Reinderien Yes, this is indeed a snippet and yes, Google is just an example. How should I proceed from now on? Post the whole thing as another question and delete this one, or do I edit this one, even though it has multiple comments and an answer now?

Comment: @Reinderien Also should I be editing my code in the question after I get feedback in the form of comments/answers? Because that's what I've been doing and that's why I go stuck with this stupid "for _ in(5)" which birthed a whole answer.

Comment: That is a very good question. In theory, all of the code reviewers should have known that this is off-topic and should not have posted answers; this would have been voted-to-close, you would have improved it, and it would have then re-opened. In practice I'm going to ask on meta.

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-questions-that-already-have-answers

Comment: @KateVelasquez In the meantime I think it is safe for you to post a new question with more code and context, after having read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions . I do not think it would be considered a duplicate. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I'm sorry that your first experience is so poor Kate. Since this has now been closed please feel free to edit the post to become on-topic, as Reinderien has suggested. Additionally the more code you proved the better we can help you improve your code. However in the future please _do not_ edit the code in the question to address answers, this is because it causes icky situations like this where you're stuck with `for _ in(5)`. When you [edit] the question so that it includes a complete script please feel free to ping me to help kick start a potential reopen.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Considering more and more people are answering off-topic questions (which they shouldn't) and the mess it has created on this one, I'm in favour of putting the revised code in a new question this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Thomas Weller's post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/241419/100620), your `for` loop only executes a single time.  You want to loop over a `range(5)`.

---

You may wish to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) to collect your unique results.  Test for containment using `a not in l` is an \$O(N)\$ operation when `l` is a list, but is \$O(1)\$ when `l` is a set, so can be significantly faster.

Moreover, since a `set` naturally cannot contain duplicate entries, the test for containment before appending the item can be entirely removed and replace with a simple `.add(a)` call.

---

The [PEP-8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends a single space on both sides of the `=` assignment operator.  So `l= []` should be written as `l = []`.

---

The variable names `l` and `a` are not at all descriptive.  You need to heavily comment the code to explain what these variables are, and what they are for, which you have not done.

Using descriptive names significantly reduces the need to comment the code, as great naming will make the code self documenting.  `l` could be `list_of_origin_headers` and `a` could be `an_origin_header`.  While those names are very self documenting, they may be too long; brevity is also important.  `origin_headers` and `origin` might be sufficient.

---

First reworking, using above points:

```
import requests

origin_headers = set()

for _ in range(5):
    origin = requests.get("https://google.com", allow_redirects=True).headers['Origin']
    origin_headers.add(origin)

# Convert set back into a list, to match the original design type
origin_headers = list(origin_headers)
```

The only tricky point in this code is `origin_headers` starts off as a set, but becomes a list at the end of the code, so a comment was necessary.

---

The code does something interesting enough to warrant its own function, which improves organization, and provides additional opportunity for documentation.

```
import requests

def fetch_origin_headers(url: str, repeat: int) -> list:
    """
    Fetch the given URL several times, and return a list containing the unique
    'Origin' headers.
    """

    if repeat < 1:
        raise ValueError("Invalid repeat.  Must be at least 1")

    origin_headers = set()

    for _ in range(repeat):
        origin = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True).headers['Origin']
        origin_headers.add(origin)

    # Return a list instead of the temporary set
    return list(origin_headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    google_origins = fetch_origin_headers("https://google.com", 5)
```

In addition to the new function, I've added some basic type-hints and the beginnings of a `"""docstring"""` to the function.  I've also added a main-guard, so this "test code"(?) fetching the results of `https://google.com` is not always executed.

---

Now that we've raise the bar a little, your Pythonista would look at the inner loop and think "set comprehension":

```
def fetch_origin_headers(url: str, repeat: int) -> list:
    """
    Fetch the given URL several times, and return a list containing the unique
    'Origin' headers.
    """

    if repeat < 1:
        raise ValueError("Invalid repeat.  Must be at least 1")

    # Accumulate results in a set, to eliminate duplicates
    origin_headers = { requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True).headers['Origin']
                       for _ in range(repeat) }

    # Return a list instead of the temporary set
    return list(origin_headers)
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Funnily, our responses are very similar. Your explanations are way better however. Do you have a pointer/links as to how `set` containment is \$ O(1) \$? I did not know this.

Comment: @AlexPovel https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not run as it is shown there.

The problem, as mentioned in the comments, is that `int` `5` is not iterable.
`range(5)` is, which would perform the action five times.

Looking for

```py
if a not in l:
    l.append(a)
```

in each loop requires looking through that list each time.

Using sets instead, this operation is still required somewhere under the hood, but likely faster (implemented on a lower level).
We also no longer have to care for it.
In the case here, a `set` can be used like the `list`, with the added benefit that `set`s can only hold unique entries.
Since you care for the *different* values, and filter duplicates out manually with the code above, this is a step in the right direction.

Generally, comprehensions are faster than manual looping and appending in Python.
There are also set comprehensions.

One last issue I had was a `KeyError` for `"Origin"`.
However, `"Date"` was available in the response, so I used that for demonstration purposes:

```py
def get_google():
    return requests.get("https://google.com", allow_redirects=True)

dates = {get_google().headers["Date"] for _ in range(5)}

print(dates)
```

My machine took more than one second for the five tries, so the output was:

```py
{'Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:43:12 GMT', 'Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:43:13 GMT'}
```

Two unique/different date entries (`str`) from five requests.

If you want to build onto that, you can for example check if the response was `ok` (`200`) with the `ok` attribute of the `response.get()` object.

Comment: It is not `int 5`, it's `in(5)` and was `in (1,5)` before edits. Probably a tupel. When editing, he broke the code. Maybe wanted it to be `in (1,)` or something